# Remove deprecated 66x48 entity icons

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We have a Dynamics CRM 2011 system on UR18. This system was upgraded from Dynamics CRM 4. From the old days, we still have entity icons in the 66x48 pixel format.

When i try to delete these webresources, I get an error that it cannot be deleted because the component is required. And right, in the dependencies of the icon I see the entity:

[image]

But on the entity, I only see the 16px and 32px image used in the customization:

[image]

How do i remove this dependency and get rid of the old icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step should be to put that entity into an unmanaged solution and export it. Extract the zip and open the customizations.xml file. CTRL + F in there for the unique name of the icon web resource and it should give you an indication of where the dependency is.

After that, depending on where it is you should be able to remove it manually in the XML, save the file, zip up the solution again and import it.

If you can paste the snippet of the XML you find in a comment I may be able to help you do that if you're unsure

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm. I found the Xml Tag `<IconLargeName>IconNew_alliancefunctionLarge</IconLargeName>` and removed it's content. After reimporting the solution, the dependency was gone.